# Chrome run fails in Azure Functions: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: azure, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, azure-functions, chromium

I wrote a web bot that uses Selenium framework to crawl. Installed ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69 and also downloaded Chromium 72.0.3626.121. The app initializes ChromeDriver with this included Chromium binary (and NOT a locally installed Chrome binary). All this perfectly works on my machine locally.

I've been attempting now to port the app to Azure Functions. I wrote a function, tested it, and it works fine locally. But once I publish it to Azure Functions it fails due to about 182 errors of type:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions

I know this happens due to exceeding the TCP connection limits of Azure sandbox, but the only attempt here was to create an instance of ChromeDriver (not even navigate anywhere yet!)

Here is a screenshot of Azure Function call log.

[image]

That error appears about 182 times in a row, and that's basically just an attempt to create a browser instance (or ChromeDriver instance, to be precise - can't be sure if that's Chromium or ChromeDriver causing the issue).

**The question:** Have anyone experienced issues with ChromeDriver/Chromium creating so many (obviously excessive) connections when launching? And what might help to avoid this.

If that's of any help, this is basically a piece of code that crashes on the last line:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = this.chromePath;
options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
if (this.headlessMode)
{
    options.AddArgument("headless");
}
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 2);

Log.LogInformation("Chrome options compiled. Creating ChromeDriverService...");

var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(this.driverPath);
driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options, timeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are running this function in a Windows Function App which is subject to quite a few limitations as described in this [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

But when running on Linux, functions are basically [run in a docker container](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2693#issuecomment-364793670), removing most of these restrictions that windows has. I believe what you are trying should be possible there.

You could either just deploy your function to a Linux Function App or even [build a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image) and use that directly as well.